# Substituição de uma coluna pela concatenação do resultado de duas colunas

Tags: postgresql

Desculpe minha ignorância.
Estou recendendo no banco de dados coordenadas X,Y (integer). Uma coluna para X e outra para Y. Entretanto elas ainda nao são do tipo geometricas. (geometry).

Aí para conseguir fazer elas virarem geometricas utilizei:

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(coluna_X, coluna_Y) from Tabela
```

E aí funcionou, (gerou uma tabela geometrica STMakePoint com os pontos X e Y, só que:
Estou tentando utilizar um gatilho para que sempre eu que receber as coordenadas X,Y elas executem essa função e vão para a coluna geom, que é a coluna que eu visualizo no Qgis.

Resumo, eu nao sei fazer um select de alguma coisa atualizar com update a coluna...
Ja pesquisei bastante e não consegui..

Alguma alma caridosa?

```
DECLARE 
        Ponto_xy geometry; -- variavel que recebe o novo valor das coord_x e y 
    
BEGIN
        SELECT ST_MakePoint(coord_x, coord_y) from tb_ro into Ponto_xy;
        
        UPDATE tb_ro SET geom = Ponto_xy;
        RETURN NEW;         
        
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

conversei com um colega da TI e me deu a seguinte dica, que funcionou muito bem para a função!

```
   BEGIN
                   
        UPDATE tb_ro SET geom =  ST_MakePoint(coord_x, coord_y);
        RETURN NEW;         
   END
```

A única coisa após a criação da função é que tem que setar na hora de criação da trigger: somente usar  INSERT e deixar desabilitado o UPDATE, já que estamos fazendo isso na função.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).